# Simple Data Writer: Configure parameters Vs user.properties file

Tags: jmeter

As I run my tests in Non-GUI mode, I am using Simple data writer with .CSV file option to write the results. I need to see the response data only when a request fails. I open the result file after the test is complete using view results tree, synthesis report and etc. but the response data says "Non-TEXT response data, cannot record: ()".
I am trying to understand:
When to use CSV and when to .jtl option? What is the major difference? When I used CSV, I am not able to see the response data. Do I need to add the below lines in the user-properties file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
```

OR/AND configure the parameters in the GUI (in Simple data Writer) by choosing 'Save response data' and 'Save as XML' and unselect 'save field names (CSV)'?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter cannot save non-text responses into XML files, you will get `Non-TEXT response data, cannot record: ()` message when [SampleResult.getDataType() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getDataType--) returns anything but `text`

You can work it around by adding a [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) and using the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) there:

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    new File('response.txt').bytes = prev.getResponseData()
}
```

Comment: But I have several child requests under each sampler so it is not feasible to add the above code for every step?